# Man In Middle Attack for HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, cryptography, ssl-certificate, man-in-the-middle

A man in middle can decrypt the certificate(public key for decryption is available on everywhere) and steal the public key for the session. Now the middle man can read all encrypted messages from web server to client. But cannot read messages from client to server. So how does HTTPS avoid this?

Comment: HTTPS doesn't have to 'avoid this', because 'this' doesn't exit in the first place. You can't read any encrypted messages with a public key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're quite simply misunderstanding how asymmetric cryptography works:

- Public keys are used to encrypt and to verify a signature (if these operations are provided by the algorithm used).
- Private keys are used to decipher and to sign.

The public key in the certificate will NOT let you decrypt anything, it's not what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

Man in the middle can see public key as part of certificate, but cannot see the private key.

Peer has to trust public key because it's signed by some CA they know in advance.

That's fundamentally it.